# TypeError : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science, nltk

I am doing an assignment project on "EDGAR-reports-Text-Analysis" where I got an error which is mentioned below. I have gone through some references but did not get the exact answer. So can anyone please help me on how to solve this problem?

Code:

```
with open(stopWordsFile ,'r') as stop_words:
        stopWords = stop_words.read().lower()
    stopWordList = stopWords.split('\n')
    stopWordList[-1:] = []
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8e9da0b999ff> in <module>
----> 1 with open(stopWordsFile ,'r') as stop_words:
      2     stopWords = stop_words.read().lower()
      3 stopWordList = stop_words.split('\n')
      4 stopWordList[-1:] = []

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

Python version = 3.7.6

Comment: Show the line when you initialize `stopWordsFile`.

Comment: you have to convert the dataframe to string. `str(dataframe)` will work. To make this post more clearer you could show the edgar [stopwords data](https://github.com/rohitharitash/EDGAR-reports-Text-Analysis).

Comment: @gribvirus74 `stopWordsFile = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Jaswal\Desktop\\New folder (2)\Data Science\\EDGAR-reports-Text-Analysis-master\\StopWords_Generic.txt')` that is the line where I am initializing **stopWordsFile**

@Willysatrionugroho [https://github.com/rohitharitash/EDGAR-reports-Text-Analysis/blob/master/StopWords_Generic.txt] - the link of **stopWordsFile** data